# 404 "failed to fetch" error with repositories when running software updater

Tags: apt, update-manager

when running Software Updater from my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop install, I get the following errors:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80], 
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80],
W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch, 
W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

How may I fix this?
Thank you.
Regards

Comment: Do you have a working Internet connection? Can you visit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ in your browser? Can you ping 91.189.88.153 from the command line? Do you have a proxy enabled?

Comment: See if you get the same error if you change the update server from your update page in system settings

Comment: @DavidFoerster The question covers both

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to remove the errors.
I noticed that I had two entries of this kind in the list of repositories:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc) universe
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc) universe (Source code)
```

After removing those 2 entries, I haven't got errors any more.
Now my question is if the two repositories I have removed are needed or I can leave them apart?
Thank you.